# Heroku + Socket.io sometimes works sometimes it doesnt

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I have read some of the articles and knows that you need xhr-polling for socket.io to work on heroku, and this is what I have so far:

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app, {origins: '*:*'});

io.configure(function () {
        io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("Connected...");
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log("Message in:" + message.toString());
    }
}
```

This code sometimes works, sometimes it stop at `console.log("Connected...")` and won't go into `socket.on('message', function(message)`. I have no idea why it only works whenever it feels like it. I have also tried restart the app but still not working.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but are you emiting `message` event on client side? Debug it and check if there are any errors.

Comment: I use send. It works when I first deployed it and somehow it stop for god knows why.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the app going to sleep? Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to setting transports to `xhr-polling` you also need to set polling duration

`io.set("polling duration", 10);`